# iPad user agent changes depending on location (work, home)

Tags: ipad, user-agent

I have found this question: https://serverfault.com/questions/583618/is-this-user-agent-string-related-to-safari?newreg=2f9ad2aada604a42b07ad369f40d3144

I originally was looking for what the "GSA" part of the user agent meant, as I am seeing the same iPad display both of the user agents from that question. When the iPad is at work it displays the "normal" Safari/iPad user agent (on AND off WiFi, so the network isn't the issue). However, at home it displays the "GSA" (Google Search Appliance) user agent.

What in the world would cause the same iPad to change its user agent based on location, using the stock Safari browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured out why this was happening, I am adding it as an answer in case someone else runs into or notices this.

This was occurring for my co-worker. It turns out that when this was tested at home, our website was opened through the Google Search App, which apparently changes the user agent to the "GSA" string. When we were testing this from work we were using Safari, which returned the good old, expected user agent string.

Not sure why the Google Search App changes the user agent, but that's what is happening.